# Python dictionary initialization

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing tutorial from book . But I have error. My class attribute is not visible. My code :

```
    class SimpleGradebook():
        def _init_(self, value = {}):
           self._grades = value

        def add_student(self,name):
           self._grades[name] = []


    book = SimpleGradebook()
    book.add_student('test')
```

it says:     print(book._grades)
AttributeError: 'SimpleGradebook' object has no attribute '_grades'

Comment: The method should be named `__init__`, not `_init_`. Note the number of underscores; you have only 1 on each side, you need *two*. Because your class only has an `_init_` method, it is never called as it is not spelled correctly

Comment: apart form that: this is a very famous pitfall of python. try this: `book2 = SimpleGradebook(); book2.add_student('test2'); print(book2._grades)`. you will note that grades now contains both entries. fix with: `def __init__(self, value = None):  self._grades = value if value else {}`.
`

Answer (score 2):

You need two underscores on `__init__`:

```
class SimpleGradebook():
    def __init__(self, value = {}):
       self._grades = value

    def add_student(self,name):
       self._grades[name] = []


book = SimpleGradebook()
book.add_student('test')
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have 1 `-` on each side of init. It should look like this:

```
class SimpleGradebook():
    def __init__(self, value = {}):
       self._grades = value

    def add_student(self,name):
       self._grades[name] = []


book = SimpleGradebook()
book.add_student('test')
```